# Linking a PHP project to Visual SVN and Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, visualsvn

I am looking for a way to be able to use VisualSVN with my PHP project.
I tried adding my whole projet into Visual Studio 2012, but the files are not added into the solution explorer, thus I cannot push the solution to the SVN server.

Is there a legit way to make a PHP/html/javascript project inside VS2012, or another way to use VisualSVN for a PHP project?

I must use this SVN since this is the only one supported by my college at the moment.

Comment: Tortoise SVN (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a subversion client, implemented as a windows shell extension. You won't need VS, and you can work with every file type. It works well with VisualSVN Server, too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found out that to use all of VisualSVN's functions I needed TortoiseSVN anyways, so I installed it. I found a way to put my whole website project files and folders into Visual Studio though. Thanks again, since I'm using Tortoise to commit and update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new javascript project and renamed the file to `index.php`. I then created folders such as `css` and `js` and dragged all my website's files into VS2012. I am now using it as a code editor and I can commit my changes right away. I wish VS had a PHP template tough (even if it wouldn't support it's syntax, I wouldn't care!), it would be less of an hassle.

Everything's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

there are a bunch of tools to create PHP projects in Visual Studio, complete with code coloring and code completion. just [search for "PHP"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=php&f%5B0%5D.Value=php&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4) in the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Comment: This question was asked on October 26th 2012. There was no tools and plugins available at the time.